# Using python ast parser to process multi line strings

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, multiline, quoting

When using the python AST parser module in combination with scripts containing multi line strings, these multi line strings are always reduced to single line quoted strings. Example:

```
import ast

script = "text='''Line1\nLine2'''"

code = ast.parse (script, mode='exec')
print (ast.unparse (code))

node = code.body[0].value
print (node.lineno, node.end_lineno)
```

The output is:

```
> text = 'Line1\nLine2'
> 1 2
```

So in spite of being a multi line string before parsing, the text is reduced to a single line quoted string when unparsed. This makes script transformation difficult, because the multi lines are getting lost when unparsing a transformed AST graph.

Is there a way to parse/unparse scripts with multi line strings correctly with AST ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Value object for the string literal contains column numbers as well as line numbers, so you can extract the original source string from the text you parsed. However, putting that together with the rest of the unparse() requires a bit of trickery. (Definitely doable, though.)

Comment: Yes, but that would require some heuristics again and quoting etc. will be a manual issue. I'm still hoping to be able to delegate this to the AST objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An examination of `ast.unparse`'s underlying [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2139583bf9350289cf137848c123f538ae03c691/Lib/ast.py#L673) reveals that the writer for the `visit_Constant` method, [`_write_constant`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2139583bf9350289cf137848c123f538ae03c691/Lib/ast.py#L1203), will produce the string `repr` unless the backslashing process is specifically avoided:

```
class _Unparse:
   ...
   def _write_constant(self, value):
      if isinstance(value, (float, complex)):
          ...
      elif self._avoid_backslashes and isinstance(value, str):
          self._write_str_avoiding_backslashes(value)
      else:
          self.write(repr(value))
```

---

By default, `_avoid_backslashes` is set to `False`, however, multiline string formatting can be properly performed by overriding `visit_Constant` and specifically calling `_write_str_avoiding_backslashes` if the string node is multiline:

```
import ast
class Unparser(ast._Unparser):
   def visit_Constant(self, node):
      if isinstance(node.value, str) and node.lineno < node.end_lineno:
         super()._write_str_avoiding_backslashes(node.value)
         return
      return super().visit_Constant(node)

def _unparse(ast_node):
   u = Unparser()
   return u.visit(ast_node)

script = "text='''Line1\nLine2'''"
print(_unparse(ast.parse(script)))
```

Output:

```py
text = """Line1
Line2"""
```

Comment: Wow, this is deep insight and indeed works. I can build a solution based on that. Thanks !

Comment: Note that by using a `_xxx` method you open yourself up to surprises when you upgrade Python and find that the method has been renamed or deleted. Not saying this is a bad solution, just be aware of the extra costs when calling non-public methods. (You could write yourself a version validation test suite that checks that non-public methods that you call are still available after upgrading.)